# Spark streaming does not insert data to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have spark-streaming code which works in client mode: it reads data from kafka, does some processing, and use spark-cassandra-connector to insert data to cassandra.

When I use the "--deploy-mode cluster", data does not get inserted, and I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-53" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/ColumnSelector
>       at com.enerbyte.spark.jobs.wattiopipeline.WattiopipelineStreamingJob$$anonfun$main$2.apply(WattiopipelineStreamingJob.scala:94)
>       at com.enerbyte.spark.jobs.wattiopipeline.WattiopipelineStreamingJob$$anonfun$main$2.apply(WattiopipelineStreamingJob.scala:88)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>       at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>       at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.ColumnSelector
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

I added dependancy for connector like this:

> "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.5.0" % "provided"

This is my application code:

```
    val measurements = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[
  Array[Byte],
  Array[Byte],
  DefaultDecoder,
  DefaultDecoder](ssc, kafkaConfig, Set("wattio"
))
  .map {
    case (k, v) => {
      val decoder = new AvroDecoder[WattioMeasure](null,
        WattioMeasure.SCHEMA$)
      decoder.fromBytes(v)
    }
  }

//inserting into WattioRaw
WattioFunctions.run(WattioFunctions.
  processWattioRaw(measurements))(
  (rdd: RDD[
    WattioTenantRaw], t: Time) => {
    rdd.cache()
    //get all the different tenants
    val differentTenants = rdd.map(a
    => a.tenant).distinct().collect()
    // for each tenant, create keyspace value and flush to cassandra
    differentTenants.foreach(tenant => {
      val keyspace = tenant + "_readings"
      rdd.filter(a => a.tenant == tenant).map(s => s.wattioRaw).saveToCassandra(keyspace, "wattio_raw")
    })
    rdd.unpersist(true)
  }
)

ssc.checkpoint("/tmp")
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: how are you specifying the connector dependency at runtime? What is your full launch command?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your JAR is available to the workers. The spark master will open up a file server once the execution of the job starts.

You need to specify the path to your uber jar either by using `SparkContext.setJars`, or via the `--jars` flag passed to `spark-submit`.

[From the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

> When using spark-submit, the application jar along with any jars included with the --jars option will be automatically transferred to the cluster. Spark uses the following URL scheme to allow different strategies for disseminating jars

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved it by removing "provided" in the dependancy list, so that sbt packaged spark-cassandra-connector to my assembly jar.

Interesting thing is that in my launch script, even when I tryed to use

> spark-submit --repositories "location of my artifactory repository" --packages "spark-cassandra-connector"

or

> spark-submit --jars "spark-cassandra-connector.jar"

both of them failed!

Answer (score 0):

scope **provided** means, you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime and that particular dependency jar will not be part of your final application War/jar you are creating hence that error.